# How to capture row data from a GridView_RowUpdated Event

Tags: .net

I'm trying to create a log table that captures a copy of any row that is edited/updated, or deleted.
I'm able to capture the edit and delete row information just fine, but the RowUpdated event capture is always blank.  The index of the row I'm trying to capture is correct on RowUpdated, but the row in the database is empty.

Here are the RowCommand and RowUpdated methods for comparison - they are basically identical, but seem to function differently.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
    protected void accountRatesGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        string type = e.CommandName.ToString();
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        while (accountRatesGridView.Rows[index] == null) { }
        GridViewRow row = accountRatesGridView.Rows[index];
        errorLabel2.Text = index.ToString();
        accountRatesLog(row, type);
    }

    protected void accountRatesGridView_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        accountRatesGridView.DataBind();
        string type = "Update";            
        GridViewRow row = accountRatesGridView.Rows[indexUpdate];
        accountRatesLog(row, type);
        errorLabel3.Text = row.ToString(); 

    }
    protected void accountRatesGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {          
        indexUpdate = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex); 
    }
```